# expected expression before double

Tags: c, double

Keeps saying that there is an expected expression before double int pt function

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 int pt (int a, int b)
 {
    int c, result;
      c = (a * a) + (b + b);
        result = double sqrt (double c);
   return result;
 }
 int main (void)
 {
     int d, e, f;
     int pt (int a, int b);
     printf("type enter after input of the two legs");
     scanf("%i", &d);
     scanf("%i", &e);
     f = pt (d,e);
     printf("the hypotenuse is %i", f);
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Others have already explained why your program doesn't compile as written, but I wonder: why did you write `pt()` to return an `int` in the first place? The hypotenuse of a right triangle whose sides are of integer length is usually not itself an integer. Also, you want `(b * b)` rather than `(b + b)`.

Comment: Because this is practice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`double sqrt (double c);` is a *function declaration*. (It is also a *function prototype*). This is how you announce that a function exists, and what parameters it takes and what it returns. The word `c` here does not mean anything, it can be omitted.

When you want to *call* a function you do not repeat this info. You just give the function name, followed by a list of values, e.g.  `sqrt(c)` .

In your code , `sqrt` has not been declared. Functions must be declared before they are called. It's not possible to simultaneously declare a function and call it; you have to declare it first.

(Historical note: this is true from C99 onwards; in C89 you could call an undeclared function, and the compiler would assume you wanted the function declared to return `int` ; this would cause undefined behaviour for any function that does not actually return `int`).

It is possible for you to provide your own declaration, so long as it matches the standard declaration:

```
double sqrt(double);
```

However it is a better idea to just use the standard declaration by going:

```
#include <math.h>
```

which works because the file `math.h` includes the line `double sqrt(double);` (or something equivalent).

Then you can write:

```
result = sqrt(c);
```

Note that you do not need to use any casts in relation to this function call. Since a function prototype exists, the compiler knows that even if you supply an `int`, it should convert that `int` to a `double` (which it knows how to do), and vice versa.

Comment: Just for the record: “it's not permitted for you to write your own declaration”—yes, it is. The standard allows to write `double sqrt(double);` instead of the `#include`. Of course, that's not really useful or anything, but “it's not permitted” is wrong.

Comment: @mafso thanks, fixed. Technically, you should do `#undef sqrt` before the self-declaration in case stdio.h included math.h, and math.h defined a macro version.

Answer (score 7):

Change

```
result = double sqrt (double c);
```

to

```
result = sqrt(c);
```

You don't have to cast `c` into a `double` when you pass it into the `sqrt` function because of implicit conversion.  If you still wanted to do the cast, the correct way would be `sqrt((double) c)`.

Also, `#include <math.h>` for use of the `sqrt` function.

---

*Note:* It's not required to cast the return type of `sqrt` to `int` (relevant since `result` is of type `int`) - however some compilers may give warnings about implicit conversion (Credit to @MattMcNabb).  It can also be good practice to put the cast in to signal to other coders that the precision loss is intentional.

Comment: A cast is not required; `result = sqrt(c);` is correct code. There is implicit conversion both ways between `double` and `int`. The only effect of using a cast here is as a hack to disable a non-standard warning that some compilers issue.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Thank you, didn't know about the two-way implicit conversion.

Answer (score 0):

It is talking about the casting that you are doing?
your casting is complaining it should be like this:

your result is an integer, so you should be casting it to int..
but if you want to cast anything to double it should be as follow

result = (double)sqrt((double) c)
or another way is double(sqrt((double) c)

but if you want to cast it as int then 
result = (int)sqrt((double) c)
or
result = int(sqrt((double) c))
hope this helps good luck